# @Html.DropDownList blank entries

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to publish a database table in a dropdownlist so that the user can pre-select some values.

My Model class looks like this:

```cs
public class ResultModel
{
    [Display(Name = "ResultId")]
    [Key]
    public int result_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Result")]
    public string result_name {get; }
}
```

My ViewModel like this:

```cs
public class ComputerImportViewModel{
    public IEnumerable<ComputerImportModel> TableComputerImport {get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<ResultModel> TableResult {get; set;}
}
```

My Context like this:

```cs
public class CMDBContext : DbContext
{
    public CMDBContext (DbContextOptions<CMDBContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<ComputerImportModel> ComputerImports { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ResultModel> Results { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ComputerImportModel>().ToTable("Computer");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ResultModel>().ToTable("Result");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And my controller like this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Import()
{
    var viewModel = new ComputerImportViewModel();

    viewModel.TableResult = await _context.Results.ToListAsync();

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

So what I want to achieve that the result table is select-able in the view:

```
@model ViewModels.ComputerImportViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownList("Result", new SelectList(Model.TableResult, "result_id" , "result_name"), "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" }))
</div>
```

But when I call the table, I get two entries, but they are blank or have the same of the table `models.ResultTable`. It seems that the visible part and index number are not correctly assigned.

I probably missing just something obvious.

Comment: you mean you are not seeing result name field in dropdown? I tried your code and working fine. do you have make result_name  read only intentionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this property to set value also like as below :

```
public string result_name {get;set; }
```

Before change

[image: before change]

After change

[image]

Comment: I just read about this some hours that the setter and getter have nothing to do with the database but it is required so that data can be written into the model, but I havent thought about it anymore. Thank you